# Exception caught by gesture. The getter 'email' was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just working on the flash chat app and its already done but now there is an error in cloud firestore:

> Exception caught by gesture
>
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The getter 'email' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: email
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
> #1      _ChatScreenState.build. (package:new_flashchat/screens/chat_screen.dart:73:48)
> #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
> #3      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
> #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
> ...
> Handler: "onTap"
> Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#09030
> debugOwner: GestureDetector
> state: possible
> won arena
> finalPosition: Offset(351.6, 104.4)
> finalLocalPosition: Offset(46.9, 16.4)
> button: 1
> sent tap down

> W/z.new_flashcha( 2344): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)

Comment: Can you provide some code? Seems you're trying to get email from a null object.

Comment: Thanks sir now i debug the code The error was that in pervious version we use (Firebase User) and now We Just (User) instead .And once again Thanks a lot.....